# Arithmetic operations on properties

Tags: c#

I've created a class that converts celsius to fahrenhait and vice versa, this is how I coded it:

```
public class TempConverter
{
    public double ValueToBeConverted { get; set; }

    public TempConverter(double valueToBeConverted)
    {
        ValueToBeConverted = valueToBeConverted;
    }

    public TempConverter()
    {
    }

    public double ConvertToFahrenheit()
    {
        return 9 / 5 * ValueToBeConverted + 32;
    }

    public double ConvertToCelsuis()
    {            
        return 5 / 9 * (ValueToBeConverted - 32);
    }
}
```

But ConvertToFahrenheit() returns 32 and the other method returns 0 whatever the value I pass down.

What I did in Main is simply instantiante an TempConverter Object and pass the value to be converted to the constructor. I did put some breakpoints and ValueToBeConverted does get the value I pass to the constructer, which in the end led me to believe that the problem is in the methods of the TempConverter class

Comment: As an aside, this is not an elegant design. What if you create a TempConverter with a Celcius value and then call ConvertToCelsuis [sic] on it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you are making *[integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Of_integers)*. Change your code as

```
public double ConvertToFahrenheit()
{
    return 9.0 / 5 * ValueToBeConverted + 32;
}

public double ConvertToCelsuis()
{            
    return 5.0 / 9 * (ValueToBeConverted - 32);
}
```